# Separating objects from the format in which they can be represented

Tags: python, design-patterns, interface, python-3.x, software-design

I often need to read a CSV file and use it to populate an internal table-like structure with the appropriate objects like this:

```
column_types = {'Car Make' : str, 'Year' : int,
  'Quantity' : int, 'Weight' : float}
# read_from_file will call str()/int()/etc., passing it
# the string that it finds in each cell
t = Table.read_from_file('mytable.txt', column_types)
t[0]['Car Model']  # 'Nissan'
t[0]['Year'] # 2010
t[0]['Quantity'] # 40
t[0]['Weight'] # 2105.53
```

Things get more complicated where built-in conversions are not enough. For instance, Quantity may be expressed in thousands in some tables. For this purpose, I created classes such as `IntegerFormat`:

```
class IntegerFormat(int): # this case is really simple, so I subclass built-in 
  def __init__(self, unit):
    self.unit = unit
  # create object from string
  def __call__(self, string):
    value = int(string) * self.unit

column_types = {'Car Make' : str, 'Year' : int,
  'Quantity' : IntegerFormat(1000)}
# no change to Table.read_from_file required
t = Table.read_from_file('mytable.txt', column_types)
t[0]['Quantity'] # 40000; now we know the correct units!
```

But I run into a problem when the class that corresponds to a given column is not very simple. For example, class `Performance` represents a few performance-related characteristics and needs to be created from strings like '300 hp, 0-60: mph 5.2 s', '540 hp, 1/4 mile: 8 sec @140 mph'. The specific string pattern will be the same throughout a single table, is known in advance, and I have clean syntax to describe it.

Now, I can follow my earlier approach and write:

```
class PerformanceFormat:
  def __init__(self, pattern):
    # convert pattern into some internal form and store it in self.pattern
    # ...
  def __call__(self, string):
    # process the string to obtain parameters that Performance.__init__ expects
    # create Performance object and return it
    # ...
    return Performance(hp, torque, quarter_mile_time)
```

But then, `PerformanceFormat` is quite tightly coupled with `Performance`: if `Performance` is modified to take into account quarter-mile final speed (rather than just quarter-mile time), `PerformanceFormat` will have to be rewritten as well.

I can move all the actual construction functionality into `Performance`, and limit `PerformanceFormat` to just storing the string pattern. But in that case, when `Table.read_from_file()` needs to read the relevant cell, it's not enough for it to have the `PerformanceFormat` instance -- how would it know that it's the `Performance` class instance that needs to be created?

I suppose I could do this:

```
column_types = {'Car Make' : str,
  'Quantity' : IntegerFormat(1000),
  'Performance' : (Performance, PerformanceType('hp: * torque: *')}
```

Here `PerformanceType` may create a standard representation that can be fed into `Performance`, greatly reducing the coupling between the two:

```
class Performance:
  def __init__(self, string, format):
    standard_representation = format(string)
    # ...
```

Perhaps even better, `PerformanceType` can just passively store the pattern, eliminating the coupling entirely:

```
class Performance:
  def __init__(self, string, format):
    standard_representation = self.to_standard(string, format)
    # ...
```

That's great. But now `Table.read_from_file` has to do something annoying: it needs to handle differently those cases where a column is described by a tuple instead of by a single callable. (Specifically, it needs to call the first element, passing it both the value it read from the cell and the second element in the tuple.)

Is there a better, cleaner approach?

Comment: Isn't that an overkill? What about using passing a regex to `PerformanceFormat` constructor and instantiate `Performance`, for example, like this: `Performance(*match.groups())`?
Or is this not flexible enough?

Comment: Oh absolutely, I could do that. The question is who would call `Performance` constructor? For `Table` class to do that, it would need to know about `Performance` class somehow.

Comment: Isn't it the same with the `IntegerFormat`? Your `IntegerFormat` class calls the `int` constructor. The only difference is that `Performance` is not a built-in class. I think that a solution like Janne's is just fine. It's simple, clear and works.
Try using it, and if you find some real-case in which it does not suffice then you could update your question/open a new question with more detailed information.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a sketch of an approach using named groups in a regex, corresponding to keyword arguments in a constructor:

```
class RegexFormat:
    def __init__(self, cls, pattern):
        self.cls = cls
        self.regex = re.compile(pattern)

    def __call__(self, string):
        return self.cls(**self.regex.match(string).groupdict())

class Performance:
    def __init__(self, hp=None, torque=None, quarter_mile_time=None)
        #....

column_types = {'Car Make' : str,
  'Quantity' : IntegerFormat(1000),
  'Performance' : RegexFormat(Performance, 
      r'hp: (?P<hp>\d+) torque: (?P<torque>\d+)')}
```